# Why am I getting a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in this example?

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

In the following code sample, I don't understand why foo method throws ConcurrentModificationException. Please help!

```
private void foo() {
        synchronized (map) {
            if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {
                Set<String> it = map.keySet();
                ArrayList<String> delArray = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String key : it) {
                    MapItem mapItem = map.get(key);
                    if (mapItem != null) {
                        long wakeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mapItem.getTimestamp();
                        if (wakeTime > MY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (mapItem.getLock() != null) {
                                mapItem.getLock().release();
                            }
                            delArray.add(key);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!delArray.isEmpty()) {
                    for (String key : delArray) {
                        map.remove(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting exception on "for (String key : it) {" line

```
private static class MapItem {
        private PowerManager.WakeLock lock;
        private long timestamp;

        public MapItem(PowerManager.WakeLock lock, long timestamp) {
            this.lock = lock;
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }

        public PowerManager.WakeLock getLock() {
            return lock;
        }

        public long getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is the stacktrace? start from the line you get that exception at and then dive in further.

Comment: i get exception on "for (String key : it) {" line

Comment: Does `mapItem.getLock().release()` remove the item from the map by any chance?

Comment: for each construct uses an iterator internally , kindly put a try catch and debug

Comment: Jon Skeet, No. It just PowerManager remove method

Comment: post your MapItem Object and value for MY_THRESHOLD, I'll try debug

Comment: MY_THRESHOLD = 60 * 60 * 1000

Comment: Do you have any other methods accessing your map without synchronization?

Comment: in class constructor i do: map  = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, MapItem>()); without synchronization. but my class is singleton

Comment: all other methods have synchronization block on map

Comment: if possible move code

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to change `map` while iterating over it, which is not allowed.
[ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html):

> If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that
>   violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this
>   exception. For example, ***if a thread modifies a collection directly
>   while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator,
>   the iterator will throw this exception***

Comment: Where i'm trying to change map?

Comment: map.remove(key); out of loop

Comment: Try `Set<String> it = new HashSet<>(map.keySet());` Do you still get the error ?

Comment: I can't simulate it. I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't put all your code here. Why the constructor if MapItem is WakeLockItem, and what
 `mapItem.getLock().release();` does? If I remove all `PowerManager.WakeLock` related code, I can execute it.

```
    private static class MapItem {
    private long timestamp;

    public MapItem(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
}

private Map<String, MapItem> map = new HashMap<>();

private void foo() {
    synchronized (map) {
        if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {
            Set<String> it = map.keySet();
            ArrayList<String> delArray = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String key : it) {
                MapItem mapItem = map.get(key);
                if (mapItem != null) {
                    long wakeTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mapItem.getTimestamp();
                    if (wakeTime > 0) {
                        delArray.add(key);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!delArray.isEmpty()) {
                for (String key : delArray) {
                    map.remove(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```